# How to perform type coercion with Relay?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay

Is relay capable of knowing that a field should be a `Date`, for example, and converting that value from a `string` to a `Date`? Is there a place that this kind of logic can be placed?

Comment: I think this should be done by the `resolve` function of the query

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it depends on where you want the conversion to happen.

If it's a variable, `Relay` containers have a `prepareVariables` prop that takes a function. I doubt this is what you're after, though, because you can't (afaik) pass a `Date` object as a var. If it's something like that,
 though, here's an example [adapted from the docs:](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-container.html#preparevariables)

```
module.exports = Relay.createContainer(ProfilePicture, {
  initialVariables: {size: 5},
  prepareVariables: prevVariables => {
    return {
      ...prevVariables,
      size: typeof prevVariables.size === 'number'? * prevVariables.size : Number(prevVariables.size),
    };
  },
});
```

If you're hoping to coerce the output of a Relay container, you'll have to either do it in the component that's consuming the props, or in a Higher Order Component. Here's the same example using the superlative [recompose](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose) (and the [recompose relay-container](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/tree/master/src/packages/recompose-relay), by the same author):

```
export default compose(
  createContainer({
      fragments: {
        widget: () => Relay.QL`
          fragment on Widget {
            myDate
          }`
      }
  }),
  withProps(props => ({myDate: props.widget.myDate instanceof myDate ? props.widget.myDate : new Date(props.widget.myDate)}))
)(ProfilePicture)
```